# How to connect an encrypted phone to a network?

Tags: lock-screens

I forgot my PIN and my phone is encrypted. I cannot access any toolbar and all I can see is a black screen with the PIN request. I tried unlocking it through "Find my Mobile" but it does not work as my phone doesn't connect to any network due to it being locked. Is there any way to connect this encrypted phone to a network?

Comment: enter correct password for decrypting block device, or do factory reset. no workaround with *find my device* because android is not even started (and google removed unlock options anyway)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is any other possible workaround besides finding the correct PIN or factory resetting the phone because the Android operating system hasn't even started yet so you can't turn on WiFi.

Comment: What you say is true for devices using Full Disk Encryption (FDE). As the OP mentions the `black screen with the pin request` this might indicate that the device indeed uses FDE. For newer devices using File Based Encryption (FBE) the PIN prompt would more look like a regular lock screen.